# MVC Cookies not seen by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var tmp = escape(document.cookie.match(/TestSession=[^;]+(;|$)/)[0]);`
```

With MVC, if I have this it works:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("TestSession", "SomeValue") {
                 Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
             };
```

But if I add:

```
cookie.Domain = "Test.com";
```

or

```
{ Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), Domain = "Test.com" };
```

The JavaScript has `tmp` as `null` or `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What result do you expect? On which domain is your site running?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you [cannot access cookies of another domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). So, if you're running the site under a different domain than *test.com* you won't be able to access the cookie.

Note: this will also be true when working from `http://localhost` - as `localhost` and `test.com` are not of the same origin.

To remedy the issue you could check the current host on the server and set the `domain` accordingly.

---

**Update** *(after comment)*

As noted by ***Andrei***, you could also add a host entry to your local host file that maps `test.com` to `localhost`. Though, you'll need to remember to comment it out when you need to navigate to the production version of the site.

Comment: What if I am running on localhost?

Comment: You can update the hosts file ( %Windows%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Comment: Great article here on how to update hosts file: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/